# Doctrine-based CodeIgniter authentication/acl system

Tags: authentication, codeigniter, doctrine, acl

I'm working on web app based on CodeIgniter/Doctrine. I've tested several auth libraries, but all of them use ActiveRecord. Is there a plugin/library that uses Doctrine, or can be adapted to Doctrine?! Or can I use both Doctrine and CodeIgniter in a project?!

Answer (score 0):

You can adapt any auth plugin/library to use Doctrine instead of ActiveRecord. It might be a lot of work to dig through the code, but essentially you'll have to figure out what the plugin/lib is attempting to do with a record (access, modify etc) and then replicate that with a doctrine statement and return the data as expected by the plugin/lib.

I've not used any Auth library/plugin with Doctrine but I've built an ACL for my app using hooks (pre-controller or post-controller works nicely) that works with Doctrine.